# What does this long sentence about physics mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence

I have a physics book and am having trouble understanding this sentence:

> When we say we are a pile of atoms, we do not mean we are merely a pile of atoms, because a pile of atoms which is not repeated from  one to the other might well have the possibilities which you see before you in the mirror.
>
> — [Richard Feynman, *Six Easy Pieces: Essentials of Physics by its most brilliant teacher*](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/604650-if-instead-of-arranging-the-atoms-in-some-definite-pattern)

There is no comma between words which makes the sentence very complicated. Could you explain what he really wants to say?

Comment: It's a very poor sentence...

Comment: Even more than that, it is complete and utter nonsense.

Comment: A Google search reveals that this quote is by Richard Feynman, one of history's most brilliant scientists. Perhaps a visiting physicist could explain it to us. Or you could try asking the question on Physics Stack.

Comment: When you Google it you find the author is: "Richard Phillips Feynman was an American theoretical physicist known for his work in the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics, the theory of quantum electrodynamics, and the physics of the ..." So how do some people here think this quote is nonsense?! What is their reason? I think it deserves an answer and can be interesting for non natives to find something through this!

Comment: I think that that sentence, as John Gribbin said, means that, in the world of very small, things do not behave in any way that we can understand.

Comment: Regardless of what the author intends the meaning to be, I agree that it is a very poor sentence indeed. I guess he was trying, rather unsuccessfully, to speak in layman's terms.

Comment: @PersianCat, being a brilliant physicist does not automatically mean being a good writer. And even good writers sometimes write poor sentences.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But stating that something is "complete and utter nonsense" would seem to be a comment on the content of the sentence, not its structure. I agree that the *sentence* is very poorly written - but whether it contains nonsense is a separate issue. :-)

Comment: A poor sentence from a scientist in physics is different with something which an ordinary person cannot understand it because of his/her lack of knowledge or poor kind of thinking and imagination. Surely people who think this sentence is a poor writing can write their reasons too and only labeling it as a nonsense doesn't make sense. I'm not sure if they knew who the writer is they had judged it the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Context is important here](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/docroot/I_01.html):

> If a piece of steel or a piece of salt, consisting of atoms one next to the other, can have such interesting properties; if water—which is nothing but these little blobs, mile upon mile of the same thing over the earth—can form waves and foam, and make rushing noises and strange patterns as it runs over cement; if all of this, all the life of a stream of water, can be nothing but a pile of atoms, how much more is possible? If instead of arranging the atoms in some definite pattern, again and again repeated, on and on, or even forming little lumps of complexity like the odor of violets, we make an arrangement which is always different from place to place, with different kinds of atoms arranged in many ways, continually changing, not repeating, how much more marvelously is it possible that this thing might behave? Is it possible that that “thing” walking back and forth in front of you, talking to you, is a great glob of these atoms in a very complex arrangement, such that the sheer complexity of it staggers the imagination as to what it can do? *When we say we are a pile of atoms, we do not mean we are merely a pile of atoms, because a pile of atoms which is not repeated from one to the other might well have the possibilities which you see before you in the mirror.*

[Emergent properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) of even simple systems can be remarkably complex, as a complexly arranged pile of atoms, our emergent properties may be even more amazing than water patterns.

Answer (score 7):

> When we say we are a pile of atoms, we do not mean we are merely a pile of atoms, because a pile of atoms which is not repeated from one to the other might well have the possibilities which you see before you in the mirror.

What he means is that human beings are different from bars of gold, even though both are "piles of atoms" because a bar of gold is just the same structure repeated over and over while a human being is not a simple, repeated pattern.

A human being is a "pile of atoms", but unlike most uninteresting piles of atoms, human beings have complex, non-repeating structure. That's what you see when you look in the mirror, not the pile of atoms but the structure.

Comment: Thank you sir your wording is so much better. I read Feynman's sentence a couple of times but I couldn't make anything out of it.